# Clearing up many-to-many in Entity Framework 6 and Entity Framework Core querying

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have to eat humble pie and admit that I thought I understood many to many in EF6 and EFCore. I have your standard example, many students many subjects scenario, but the problem comes when I try to navigate the collections to get at specific properties during projections that I get stuck and can't figure out how to use either `Select` or `SelectMany` to get at properties in my projection.

So for example how would I use either `Select` or `SelectMany` to finish this?

I need to understand properly these two LINQ methods but can anyone help me?

Here is an example of where I'm stuck:

```
return await _db.Subjects
                .Include(s => s.Teachers)
                .Include(s => s.Students)
                .Where(s => s.Students.Select(x => x.Class.ClassName).Contains(classname))
                .Select(s => new SubjectViewModel
                        {
                            Class = s.Students.Select(p => p.Class.ClassName)
                        })
```

So how do I complete this, do I do a `SelectMany` or `Select`? Oh and can anyone point me to some content other than MSDN to properly understand `Select` and `SelectMany`? Also can anyone show me how this would be done in EFCore? I think I just need help.

Comment: Small point, but this is **linq-to-entities** rather than linq-to-sql as one of the tags suggests.

Comment: sorry for the mix up. will edit it accordingly.

Comment: I think you will get a quicker response if you post your class definitions of Teacher, Student, Subject and Class so we can see the relationships. Also the SubjectViewModel would be useful to see the overall intended output.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what we have to work with (as @Matthew Cawley said in the comment) if you use `Select` you get an object of type `IEnuberable<IEnumerable<string>>` or `IQueryable<IQueryable<string>>` which is a list of lists of strings.

If you need only one list of strings you can use `SelectMany` to iterate just like `Select` but flatten the results into one collection and then applies the selector you passed `p => p.Class.ClassName`.

If you want to concatenate them into a single string you can use `string.Join(",", <collection>)` but not directly in the projection if you are using linq-to-sql because it wouldn't know how to translate that into sql code.

Comment: Your answer is pretty helpful sir. God bless